# APNS Push notifications not working in background mode when app is installed from ipa but same works for direct xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Foreground as well as background Notifications work for iOS 9 but when it comes to iOS 10 and above, only foreground alert is working and I am not receiving anything in background.

I am using FCM Plugin v 3.0.3, Xcode 9.1 and iOS platform in cordova is 4.5.0.

I am sure that I am using right certificates.

I am using correct provisioning profile while still no luck.

I am stuck on this for quite long. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did u enable background modes for remote notifications in capabilities?

Comment: Have you added "Required background modes" key in plist?

Comment: @ShivamTripathi yes i did that

Comment: did you set the priority for the push notification to high, I've experienced this before and changing the priority does work.

Comment: @ArpitDongre yes, it's there

Comment: @MalcolmnRoberts yes, that too.. I even set 'content-available=1', didn't help.

Comment: Are you calling    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()  before    FirebaseApp.configure() ?

Comment: Perhaps show a alert when the token has successfully be created and registered just to make sure

Comment: @MalcolmnRoberts i am able to get token registered successfully..